# Constructor vs. parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, class-constructors

What is the difference between:

```
class Pitch(var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5) {

    constructor(capacity: Int): this()

}
```

and

```
class Pitch(var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5, capacity: Int)
```

What advantages does the constructor provide?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your class like this:

```
class Pitch (var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5) {

    constructor(capacity: Int): this() {}

}
```

you can create an instance of `Pitch` using constructor without parameters, i.e.:

```
val p = Pitch()

// also you can invoke constructors like this
val p1 = Pitch(30)     // invoked secondary constructor
val p2 = Pitch(30, 20) // invoked primary constructor
```

---

When you define your class like this:

```
class Pitch (var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5, capacity: Int) {

}
```

all parameters are required except those with default values. So in this case you can't use constructor with empty parameters, you need specify at least one parameter `capacity`:

```
val p = Pitch(capacity = 40)
```

So in the first case you have an advantage of using constructor without parameters. In the second case if you want to call constructor and pass `capacity` parameter you should name it explicitly when using constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> What advantages does the constructor provide?

In your first snippet you define two constructors, one primary and one secondary. This special thing about the primary constructor is that is always has to be invoked by any secondary constructor.

```
class Pitch (var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5) /* primary constructor */ {
    // secondary constructor invokes primary constructor (with default values)
    constructor(capacity: Int): this()
}
```

In both cases: `Pitch()` and `Pitch(10, 20)` the primary constructor is invoked. Pitch(10) would invoke the secondary constructor.

If you want to invoke the primary constructor for this instantiation `Pitch(10)` you have to specify the parameter name explicitely like this:

```
Pitch(width = 30)
```

You can also turn it around and set `height` explicitely and leave `width` with its default value:

```
Pitch(height = 30)
```

As you see using two parameters (properties) with default values for each leaves you with 4 possibilities to instantiate the class via primary constructor alone.

Specifying a secondary constructor is especially useful to provide an alternative way to instantiate a class.

---

Using it like this

```
class Pitch(var width: Int = 3, var height: Int = 5, capacity: Int)
```

would only make sense when you can't deduce the value of `capacity` from `width` and `height`. So, it depends on your use-case.

Comment: When you say `If you want to invoke the secondary constructor for this instantiation Pitch(10) you have to specify the parameter name explicitly like this:` `Pitch(width = 30) // now the secondary constructor is called` - did you mean to use `capacity` there instead of `width`?

Comment: Thanks. So the bottom line is - if you specify all or none of the primary constructor parameters in your class instantiation, it won't invoke the secondary class. And if you don't specify all the primary parameters but you specify the same number of parameters as the secondary constructor (in the above case, 1) then it will invoke the secondary constructor?

Comment: @Zorgan "[...] if you specify all or none of the primary constructor parameters in your class instantiation, it won't invoke the secondary class [constructor]." in this case yes! "And if you don't specify all the primary parameters but you specify the same number of parameters as the secondary constructor (in the above case, 1) then it will invoke the secondary constructor?" Yes it will! but note, that it does not have to do with the fact which one is the primary and which one is the secondary constructor.

Comment: @Zorgan The compiler will take the first constructor (not matter if primary or secondary) that matches the signature without having to insert default values. see here: https://pl.kotl.in/SkEaEEjmV

Comment: f you want to be sure and the parameter/property names differ use named parameters like shown above. I can't hurt anyway. :)